# Managing different resource directories

Tags: java, eclipse, file, maven, nio

I'm using Eclipse with Maven m2e plugin. My project uses configuration xml files located under `config`. Maven project layout says you should put stuff like that in `srv/main/resources` and here the trouble starts...

In the appication the `config` directory is hard wired relative to the project root. Can I somehow, maybe even trough the POM, trick Eclipse and Maven to make the software runnable even if the the files are in `src/main/resources`?

**EDIT:** Maven layout says only src, target, pom.xml and some txt files are in the root. But my deployed software requires config in the root. This doesn't quite fit together if my appilcation calls something like new File("config/someXml.xml"). My software would have to look in config/someXml.xml and src/main/resoruces/config/someXml.xml depending on if the software is deployed or debugging.

How do other projects do this? Do I somehow have to change my code for supplying the directory path?

Comment: You've written `srv/...` - you mean `src/...`, right?

Comment: Thanks, that's about the 10th time today that I got that wrong :-)

Comment: Is your project a plain old console app? How does the underlying app framework launch your executable jar?

Comment: Through an .sh file which calls `java -jar ...`. The apps are very independant, only the configuration location has to be fixed so that the framework or some human can access it at this knwon location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, the most common and efficient way is making you application resolve the required config file from multiple place in a pre-defined order, pseudo code:

```
Properties config = null;
// try load config file from pre-defined location, first attempt
config = read("config/config.xml");
// if nothing is here, load config file from classpath, default.
if (config == null)
  config = read("src/main/resources/config.xml");
```

The config.xml under src/main/resources always come with the final executable jar (inside the jar), if nothing is presented in config folder, always use this as default. So in development, app can use src/main/resources/config.xml without concerning config/config.xml existence, when go to deployment, it will start using config/config.xml if presented.

Comment: this is a interesting but kind of most brute force approach :-) I think I will have to delete the config.xml in the jar to pervent some production software from accessing the test area by mistake and fail quickly instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you can specify additional resource directories in a `build` element of your pom.

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>config</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Beware that all it does is to copy all files from `config` directory to your output directory ( by default `target\classes` ), so from the build process view it really does not matter whether they are in `config` or in `src/main/resources` (just more typing on your part).

Answer (score 1):

Change the application. Your application should not know what the project root is. It's not clear what that would even mean if it is was running from a jar file that you've distributed.

The most conventional thing would be to move the configuration files into `src/main/resources` or whatever and then load them as [classpath resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).

If you don't want to do that, then supply a config directory path to the application as a system property, using a `-D` argument to java, and look for the config files relative to that. In Eclipse, you can set that in a launch configuration. On the command line, you can set it in a wrapper script that runs your application. Or, if you're using an app server or other container, using some mechanism specific to that.

Comment: The app runs in a framework that ensures that the `config` directory is always at the same relative position to the jar, but the framework doesn't care about the Maven layout. The `config` folder has to be accessible through the file system at `./config` relative to the root because other processes access the files. Therefore there are no possibilities to change the deployment structure...

Answer (score 0):

don't know if thats exactly what youre trying to achive, but did you have a look at the `maven-resources-plugin`, I think Alexander already stated?

you can define and copy the additional resources needed for the project to run,
I quote.. [1]

> You can use the mojo copy-resources to copy resources which are not in the default maven layout or not declared in the build/resources element and attach it to a phase

[1] http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html